# Jquery tooltip does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

Here is the jquery code for a tooltip popup when i hover over a link.

**Error** is when i hover over it, it sets title to nothing show it will show once and then nothing will come up if i re hover over it.

When i remove this.title = ""; it works but the link title comes  up aswell

**HTML**

```
 < a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Name< br>Test">ToolTip< /a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 this.tooltip = function(){ 

    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;               

$("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
    this.t = this.title;
    this.title = "";                                          
    $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");        
},
function(){
    this.title = this.t;        
    $("#tooltip").remove();
}); 
$("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to perform a check if the title is empty first.  The reason why is because you're blindly setting the `t` variable no matter what and clearing the title.  Try this:

```
this.tooltip = function(){ 
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;

    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){
        if(this.t === undefined || this.t.length == 0) {

           this.t = this.title;
           this.title = "";
        }
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
    }, function(){
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});
```